# Socket UDP Send e Receive C#

Tags: c#

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em c# que utiliza UDP, o problema é que não consigo responder ao cliente. Recebo o seguinte erro: Additional information: Uma solicitação de envio ou recebimento de dados não foi permitida porque o soquete não está conectado e (durante o envio em um soquete de datagrama usando-se uma chamada sendto) não foi fornecido um endereço.

Segue o sistema:
Servidor:

```
string data = "";
            byte[] d = new byte[1024];

            Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);


            IPEndPoint remoteIPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 6969);


            Console.WriteLine(" S E R V E R   IS   S T A R T E D ");
            Console.WriteLine("* Waiting for Client...");
            server.Bind(remoteIPEndPoint);
            while (data != "q") {
                //data = Console.ReadLine();

                server.Receive(d);
                data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(d);
                Console.WriteLine("Handling client at " + remoteIPEndPoint + " - ");
                Console.WriteLine("Message Received " + data.TrimEnd());

                d = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("oi");
                server.Send(d);
                Console.WriteLine("Message sended to" + remoteIPEndPoint + " " + data);

            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter Program Finished");
            Console.ReadLine(); //delay end of program
            server.Close();  //close the connection
```

Cliente

```
string data = "";
        byte[] d = new byte[1024];

        Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);


        IPEndPoint remoteIPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 6969);


        Console.WriteLine(" C L I E N T   IS   S T A R T E D ");

        server.Connect(remoteIPEndPoint);

        Console.WriteLine("* Server connected...");

        while (data != "q") {
            d = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("teste");
            server.Send(d);
            Console.WriteLine("Message sended to" + remoteIPEndPoint + " " + data);



            server.Receive(d); 
            data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(d);
            Console.WriteLine("Received from server: "+data);


        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter Program Finished");
        Console.ReadLine(); //delay end of program
        server.Close();  //close the connection
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UDP é um protocolo que não requer conexão, ao contrário do TCP. O que você precisa é um endpoint que irá receber o pacote.

Seu código no cliente pode conter algo similar ao trecho abaixo:

```
//Prepara um socket para ser utilizado como emissor
Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram,
ProtocolType.Udp);

//Prepara o endereço-alvo
IPEndPoint endPointServidor = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 6969);

//Transforma o conteúdo a ser enviado em um array de bytes
byte[] d = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("teste");

//Envia o conteúdo [d] para o servidor [endPointServidor]
server.SendTo(d, endPointServidor);
```

Seu servidor, então, pode conter um código similar a este:

```
//Prepara um socket para ser utilizado como receptor
Socket receiver = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

//Prepara o cliente Udp, ouvindo na porta 6969
UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(6969);

//Inicia a captura de pacotes. O metodo gerenciaRetorno sera chamado
//  sempre que um conteúdo via UDP chegar ao servidor
receiver.BeginReceive(gerenciaRetorno, listener);

    private static void gerenciaRetorno(IAsyncResult li)
    {
        IPEndPoint recEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        Byte[] buffer = ((UdpClient)li.AsyncState).EndReceive(li, ref recEP);

        //[mensagem] conterá o conteúdo recebido.
        string mensagem = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);

        //re-arma o socket para recepção
        receiver.BeginReceive(gerenciaRetorno, li.AsyncState);
    }
```

Fonte: [C# UDP Socket client and server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786668/c-sharp-udp-socket-client-and-server), SO original.

Comment: Opa Ono, se não for pedir demais, você poderia editar essa resposta comentado que cada função faz e o que são os parâmetros. Sou iniciante em C# e programação Client+Server (que não seja web JS+PHP)

Comment: @KaduAmaral - sem problema, aqui vai a versão com comentários e algumas correções.

Comment: Ono, estou com algum problema no método `BeginReceive`, o VS aponta que ele não tem overload de 2 parâmetros, os primeiros geralmente são `bytes[] buffer` ou `IList<ArraySegment<byte>>`. Eu coloquei esse método no construtor de uma classe que eu chamei de server, então essa função `gerenciaRetorno` pode ser um método, ou deve estar dentro do construtor também?

Answer (score 0):

Eu tive esse problema recentemente. Eu resolvi o problema colocando um "Sleep" de  500 milissegundos antes de enviar os bytes.